# How to set retention time in Netflix Conductor?

Tags: mysql, netflix, retention, conductor, netflix-conductor

We use MySQL as database for working with Netflix Conductor.
Is it possible to set time to keep workflow execution history (in MySQL and in Elasticsearch)?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such option but you can schedule tasks to call

```
/workflow/{workflowId}/remove?archiveWorkflow=false
```

which will clean the workflows from both database and elasticsearch for workflows that fits your criteria.